# Natural Join Implementation Python

Tags: python, sql, natural-join

I am working on implementing natural join in python. The first two lines show the tables attributes and the next two lines each tables' tuples or rows.

Expected Output:

```
[['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A'], 
 ['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'Y'], 
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'A'], 
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'Y'], 
 ['S', 2, 'B', 'b', 'S']]
```

And what I got:

```
[['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A', 'Y'], 
 ['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A', 'Y']]
```

I have looked through the code and everything seems to be right, I would appreciate any help.

```
t1atts = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
t2atts = ('B', 'D', 'E')

t1tuples = [['A', 1, 'A', 'a'], 
            ['B', 2, 'Y', 'a'], 
            ['Y', 4, 'B', 'b'], 
            ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a'], 
            ['S', 2, 'B', 'b']]

t2tuples = [[1, 'a', 'A'], 
            [3, 'a', 'B'], 
            [1, 'a', 'Y'], 
            [2, 'b', 'S'], 
            [3, 'b', 'E']]

def findindices(t1atts, t2atts):
  t1index=[]
  t2index=[]
  for index, att in enumerate(t1atts):
    for index2, att2 in enumerate(t2atts):
      if att == att2:
        t1index.append(index)
        t2index.append(index2)
  return t1index, t2index

def main():
  tpl=0; tpl2=0; i=0; j=0; count=0; result=[]
  t1index, t2index = findindices(t1atts, t2atts)
  for tpl in t1tuples:
    while tpl2 in range(len(t2tuples)):
      i=0; j=0
      while (i in range(len(t1index))) and (j in range(len(t2index))):
          if tpl[t1index[i]] != t2tuples[tpl2][t2index[j]]:
            i=len(t1index)
            j=len(t1index)
          else:
            count+=1
          i+=1
          j+=1
      if count == len(t1index):
        extravals = [val for index, val in enumerate(t2tuples[tpl2]) if index not in t2index]
        temp = tpl
        tpl += extravals
        result.append(tpl)
        tpl = temp
      count=0
      tpl2+=1
  print result
```

Comment: Are you trying to join ? t1tuples and t2tuples ?

Comment: yes, I am. Then, the output will be a list of tuples as well.

Comment: But, I am not able to see any rules to apply to get '['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A', 'Y']' from ['A', 1, 'A', 'a'] + [1, 'a', 'A']

Comment: in natural join, every tuple in t1tuples is compared with every tuple in t2tuples...if a match is found, that tuple is attached to the result

Comment: That is the output I got or the incorrect output. Please look under "expected output" to see what the program should output. You can also run the program yourself by calling main() and see the output.

Comment: Ok so, i found each element of ['A', 1, 'A', 'a'] in [1, 'a', 'A'], right so, when i joined I got ['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 1, 'a', 'A']

Comment: It is the natural join. You do not add the [1 'a'] again. Please assume that the expected output is correct and I need to fix the code to get the expected output.

Comment: Please check it, and let me know

Comment: Why "delete" the question? You should accept the answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. I'd do some more refactoring, etc before calling it done

```
import pprint

t1atts = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
t2atts = ('B', 'D', 'E')

t1tuples = [
    ['A', 1, 'A', 'a'],
    ['B', 2, 'Y', 'a'],
    ['Y', 4, 'B', 'b'],
    ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a'],
    ['S', 2, 'B', 'b']]

t2tuples = [
    [1, 'a', 'A'],
    [3, 'a', 'B'],
    [1, 'a', 'Y'],
    [2, 'b', 'S'],
    [3, 'b', 'E']]


t1columns = set(t1atts)
t2columns = set(t2atts)
t1map = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(t1atts)}
t2map = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(t2atts)}

join_on = t1columns & t2columns
diff = t2columns - join_on

def match(row1, row2):
   return all(row1[t1map[rn]] == row2[t2map[rn]] for rn in join_on)

results = []
for t1row in t1tuples:
    for t2row in t2tuples:
        if match(t1row, t2row):
            row = t1row[:]
            for rn in diff:
                row.append(t2row[t2map[rn]])
            results.append(row)

pprint.pprint(results)
```

And I get the expected results:

```
[['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A'],
 ['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'Y'],
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'A'],
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'Y'],
 ['S', 2, 'B', 'b', 'S']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the solution please verify and let me know if it works for you:

I change little bit of naming to understood myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

table1 = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
table2 = ('B', 'D', 'E')

row1 = [['A', 1, 'A', 'a'],
        ['B', 2, 'Y', 'a'],
        ['Y', 4, 'B', 'b'],
        ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a'],
        ['S', 2, 'B', 'b']]

row2 = [[1, 'a', 'A'],
        [3, 'a', 'B'],
        [1, 'a', 'Y'],
        [2, 'b', 'S'],
        [3, 'b', 'E']]

def findindices(table1, table2):
    inter = set(table1).intersection(set(table2))
    tup_index1 = [table1.index(x) for x in inter]
    tup_index2 = [table2.index(x) for x in inter]]
    return tup_index1, tup_index2

def main():

    final_lol = list()

    tup_index1, tup_index2 = findindices(table1, table2)

    merge_tup = zip(tup_index1, tup_index2)

    for tup1 in row1:
        for tup2 in row2:
            for m in merge_tup:
                if tup1[m[0]] != tup2[m[1]]:
                    break
            else:
               ls = []
               ls.extend(tup1)
               ls.append(tup2[-1])
               final_lol.append(ls)
    return final_lol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(main())
```

Output:

```
[['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'A'],
 ['A', 1, 'A', 'a', 'Y'],
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'A'],
 ['A', 1, 'Y', 'a', 'Y'],
 ['S', 2, 'B', 'b', 'S']]
```